# Count number of rows in a table

Tags: python, openpyxl

First Question on the Overflow, I'll get to it.

Using python 3.7 with openpyxl

I have a large excel document with several sheets, each with several tables. 
I'm using for loops to iterate through each sheet and table, and would like to grab the amount of rows per table.

I've had a look about with google-fu but to no avail.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#Import excel reader/writer
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os

#Open the execl spreadsheet
try:
    wb = load_workbook(os.path.expanduser( "~/Documents/EST Attendance.xlsx"))
except:
    print("File not found, ensure the file is placed under Documents and named 'EST Attendance'")

#Loop through all the sheets in workbook
for sheet in wb:

    #Print the current worksheet
    print(str(sheet))
    #Loop through all the tables in the workbook, print "Name" : "Rows"
    for table in sheet._tables:
        print("    " + str(table.name) + " : " + str(table.nrows))

print("Loop successful")
```

The script crashses at:

```
str(table.nrows)
```

Because I have no idea what to put there to get a row count.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Read [openpyxl.readthedocs - accessing-many-cells](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells)

Comment: I havent worked on openpyxl. However, looking at the doc, you may need to do `from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table, Tables` based on my reading of [link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet_tables.html?highlight=tables), and use `str(table.totalsRowCount))` based on [this link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.table.html?highlight=openpyxl.worksheet.table)

Comment: Note that "Max row" and "max column"  are surprisingly tricky concepts. You would think they mean "the least row such that all rows above it  are completely blank" but  it may mean   something  like  "the least row such that all rows above it were never edited".

Comment: You should look at the source of the Table class to see how it defines the cells it covers.

Comment: @Joshua-Fox It's not really difficult to understand the highest row and column of a worksheet. Notions of blankness are trickier.

Comment: @CharlieClark The tricky part, from my perspective, is that “'Used Cell' is defined as Cell containing formula, formatting, value that has even been used, EVEN THOUGH THAT VALUE WAS DELETED".  http://access-excel.tips/last-row-and-last-column/

Comment: It's best to think of every worksheet as 16,384 x 1,000,000 cells so `max_row`, etc. are merely short cuts for different contexts: a cell might have no value but still have a comment attached. `(1, 1, max_row, max_column)` represents the boundaries of the cells. Client-code is responsible for additional distinction.

Comment: @CharlieClark I really can't find a way to reference the table's data at all?(Position, size, etc) I'm not familiar with the structure of objects, and referencing them. I would use the sheet and and count the non-blank rows, but there may be more than 1 or 2 tables per sheet.

Comment: Actually, after some further research, I was able to access the ref, I think i was spelling the references wrong :/.

Comment: I have a similar issue.  I see comments referring to "max_row" which refers to the sheet, not the table. Therefore, if there is more than one table, it will return the bottom row of the longest table. And what if the table begins on row 1000 and has a header and 3 rows?  It will still return 1003 - not a very accurate row count! The `ref` attribute gives a string that must be parsed, and to get the `_table` attribute in the first place requires access to a protected member of the class.  Surely there is a better way!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide the version of Openpyxl that you are using as the functionality to find the max row count has changed over different versions. Run the following to find out the version :

```
import openpyxl
openpyxl.__version__
```

I am using version 2.5.0 and in this version to get the max row count I just execute `sheet.max_row` and execute `sheet.max_column` for getting the maximum columns.

Comment: Hi, the version of openpyxl Im using is 2.5.12
I also tried using max_row, on the table and got the error:
   AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'max_row'

Comment: max_row and max_column are properties and should never be called as methods. However, that's not the issue here.

Comment: @CharlieClark Yes you are right. it should be `sheet.max_row`

Comment: Because they are properties.

Comment: How would I get this to work with a table instead of a sheet?